# Using arcpy and script toolbox to add the date to a attribute table

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, date, python-script-tool

I would like some information on how to add a date to an attribute table, by adding a user specified date in a script tool that will update the polygons attribute table. In short I have two polygons that I wish to calculate the difference in time, in hours between them. The date is determined by specification inside a script box, seen in the image below.

[image: Screenshot of tool]

I would like to use code that goes along with my tool and I need to figure out what I'm missing in the following code; (This is the simple code for the tool)

```
import arcpy 

Mother1 = sys.argv[1]
date1= sys.argv[2] ### I believe date style is in format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss 
Mother2 = sys.argv[3]
date2 = sys.argv[4]

try:
    arcpy.AddField_management(Mother1,"Date","DATE","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","#")
    arcpy.AddField_management(Mother2,"Date","DATE","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","#")
```

Then, I tried adding the date to the field such as this;

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Mother1, "Date", date1)
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Mother2, "Date", date2)
```

But that did not work.

I would like to add the date to the attribute table and then also be able to calculate the difference between the two dates, but need to get the date into the attribute table before I can calculate anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not assume it is a date.  I would make sure the date and time is captured as a string and create a python expression using the strptime function and use a PYTHON_9.3 calculation to have the entire date and time calculated.  VB Date expressions should be in the format of #date#, but they are not reliable, since they only preserve the date, not the time, and you cannot control how they interpret different string date formats, like you can with the strptime function using a PYTHON_9.3 field calculation.  (Edit:  I adjusted the try block location to make sure that any date conversion error is handled in the except block and I added logic to determine if the Date field should be added or if it already exists).  The revised code now formats the strptime function expression as a string that allows the Field Calculator to do the date conversion using the strptime function, not the script:

```
import arcpy

from datetime import datetime

try:

    Mother1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    print arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    ### Confirm from print that date string is in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
    ### Make a Field Calculation expression that will use strptime to get a datetime. 
    date1 = "datetime.datetime.strptime('" + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) + "', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
    ### VB Script calculations use "#date#" strings to create dates, but not datetime 
    ### date1 = '#' + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) + '#'
    Mother2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
    date2 = "datetime.datetime.strptime('" + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) + "', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')"
    ### VB Script calculations use "#date#" strings to create dates, but not datetime
    ### date2 = '#' + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) + '#'

    fields = arcpy.ListFields(Mother1)
    addfield = True
    for field in fields:
        if field.name.upper() == "DATE":
            addfield = False
    if addfield:
        arcpy.AddField_management(Mother1,"Date","DATE","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","#")

    fields = arcpy.ListFields(Mother2)
    addfield = True
    for field in fields:
        if field.name.upper() == "DATE":
            addfield = False
    if addfield:
        arcpy.AddField_management(Mother2,"Date","DATE","#","#","#","#","NULLABLE","NON_REQUIRED","#")

    arcpy.CalculateField_management(Mother1, "Date", date1, "PYTHON_9.3")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(Mother2, "Date", date2, "PYTHON_9.3")
except Exception as e:
    print e.message

    # If using this code within a script tool, AddError can be used to return messages 
    #   back to a script tool.  If not, AddError will have no effect.
    arcpy.AddError(e.message)
```

Comment: +1 I was just starting to look at this and my first comment on the question was going to be that I would use `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()` rather than `sys.argv[]` which you have covered.  However, the focus of this question should always have been date/string formatting and you have used a technique that I am sure I will be looking back at next time I need to handle dates in ArcPy.

Comment: :) Almost! I will use the getparameterastext format. The format in which I'm printing the code is 2014-12-01 10:37:28 PM. However when I check what date1 = datetime.strptime(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1), '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p') is by print date1. I get 2014-12-01 22:37:28.

Comment: If you printing date1 after the conversion then that makes no difference (it is a valid date if the conversion succeeded).  It only makes a difference what print arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) prints like.  Are you saying that the print arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) strings is 2014-12-01 22:37:28?  If so that isn't a problem.  I just have to match that format, so I changed the strptime format to:  date1 = datetime.strptime(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: I believe my add field management is incorrect, it seems that it does not want to add a date format correctly, rather it wants to add the year from amount of days starting at 1900. The error arises from  inputting 2014-12-01 22:37:28, says that its in string format and error 999999 comes up, using just python with arcpy.CalculateField_management("Mother1", "Date", "THEDATE") and lets says THEDATE is "2014-12-01 22:37:28" I get the 99999 error, however if THEDATE is something like 3650 then I get it to work, but the date is 1909-12-28 which counts from 1900... I'm getting it slowly :)

Comment: You cannot use a date string in the calculation without enclosing it in the format "#date#"  The hashtags enclosing the string tell the field calculator to use it as a date.  So for the field calculation you may not want a real date and just use:  date1 = '#' + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) + '#'. You also could use an updatecursor to accomplish same thing as a field calculation and the cursor would correctly accept the real python date.  The real python dates could also do the date difference operation without every storing the actual dates in a table.

Comment: You should update your code to show what you are now trying, since I really cannot tell what line you are referring to, since you are not repeating my code to explain the problem.  I have no idea what "THEDATE" represents.  Is it a real python date, a string, ???

Comment: The hashtage #date# format applies to VB Script calculations, which is what you are using by not specifying the calculation type (the parameter after the date expression).  For Python calculations I believe you would have to set the expression up to use the strptime function to get the field calculator to treat the string as a date, but I believe that function expression needs to be a string expression to work in a script so that the field calculator does the date conversion, not the script.  It trips me up often, since it works one way in Desktop and another in a script.

Comment: Using the date1 = '#' + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) + '#'  solved the problem. It adds the date to the table now :) It doesn't add the time for h:m:s to the table tho, which is fine as long as I can calculate the difference in time between them.

Comment: The calculation should now work if you use my latest revised code.  I still recommend the strptime function expression over the VB Script #date# expression, since the strptime can be adjusted to handle many different date formats, while the VB Script #date# function does not let you specify the date format it accepts.

Comment: Use the revised code to get the date and time using the Python_9.3 calculation.  The strptime function correctly calculates the entire date and time in my script now that I have converted it to a string expression for the calculator, rather than doing the conversion in the script directly.  VB Script should not be used if you want the time preserved, since it will strip it out, and the Python version will make the follow up calculation easier for the difference.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for your help, your revised version works, and I do see the usefulness of keeping it in python format, thanks again!